# EditorConfig - simplify boolean evaluations?

Tags: c#, editorconfig

Is there an EditorConfig setting for simplifying boolean evaluations in `if` statements? e.g.

```cs
// prefer:
if (thingy)

// over:
if (thingy == true)
```

and

```cs
// prefer:
if (!thingy)

// over:
if (thingy == false)
```

Comment: in such a way that the compiler warns you or auto refactor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the corresponding analyzer with this in your .editorconfig:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0100.severity = warning
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0100

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a setting in EditorConfig. Note that EditorConfig isn't really a static analysis tool, but a configuration setting for formatting files with regard to indentation, tabs vs spaces etc.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such built-in VS editor config. Usually, you would use either [StyleCop](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop), or [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and alike for code style rules and refactorings like that.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio one of the cleaner solutions would be to use a plugin. Personally I use Resharper.

Take a look at the Resharper plugin from Jetbrains.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Docs on their code generation features here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html

Docs on their code style and formatting features here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the .editorconfig in your solution path and if you're using VSCode, install [official C# plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp). To enable `.editorconfig` validation just go to settings (ctrl/command + ,) > "Extensions" > "C# configuration" > Check "Omnisharp: Enable Editor Config Support". Also, make sure option "Format: Enable" is checked.

If you want to actually make build fail, you could use [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle NuGet package](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/roslyn/package/nuget/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle/3.6.0-3.20177.13) in the project you want to validate code style. This will generate build failure if the code is not compliant to `.editorconfig`. [More informations in about this issue.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/33558#issuecomment-605974524)